# Ubuntu+Unity: text selection event

Tags: events, ubuntu, textselection, ubuntu-unity

Subject: I have Ubuntu with Unity. I select text in different tools, like PDF Reader, Libre Office and so on. Can I get this event object (selection) somehow? I want to do some processing on this event.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection is the selected object but what do you mean by "event"?  The event of selecting?  Maybe look at `xev`.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.